# Magento2.3 Hide new address form button on checkout page based on customer groups

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to hide this new address button based on customer group. I want to use conditions for hiding that button. If anyone knows please let me know.

[image: magento]

[image: Check still loading]

Check this still loadind and console.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/mixin/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/shipping-mixin.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'ko'
    ], function (
        $,
        _,
        ko
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return function (target) {
            return target.extend({
                /**
                 * @inheritDoc
                 */
                initialize: function () {
                    this._super();
                    var self = this;
                    var quoteData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteData;
                    var customerGroupId = parseInt(quoteData.customer_group_id);
                    if (!this.isFormInline) {
                        _.each([3,4], function (value) {
                            if (value == customerGroupId) {
                                self.isNewAddressAdded(true);
                            }
                        } );
                    }
                    return this;
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Brother @sohel I want to show this button for two customer groups so what would be the code ?

Comment: My checkout page is loading stll and not working properly. can you update ?

Comment: You modify this logic: if (!this.isFormInline && (customerGroupId != 4)) {

Comment: Remove static content, build static content

Comment: I removed static content but checkout is still loading. Is this code working for you ?

Comment: yes, M2.3.4. Show your console error. Clear your browser JS cache.

Comment: I need this in magento 2.3.2 ??

Comment: Should work. clear your browser js cache.

Comment: Can you update your code for two customer groups.? I need button visible for 2 customer groups otherwise it should be hide ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107101/discussion-between-yousaf-and-sohel-rana).

Comment: Updated console in question

Comment: Updated answer. Do you think that console error is for my answer? Your console error says something wrong your amazon payment.

Comment: But my checkout page is still loading after add your code. I don't know why. Why it is still loading any idea ?